# Customer Community User Import in Production without Sending Mail

Tags: customer-community

We have a requirement in which we want to import Customer Community users in Production without notifing them. How can this be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

Below Picture shows how to Configure email service go to community then click on manage link then below window will be open where You can customize email sercvices , Community Admin can send email when member are added to community and Stop Emailing When used add to the community

[image: BY Email Setting You can Restrict Email When the user add to community or community is activate]